# solr: what is the difference between cloud and standalone mode

Tags: solr, lucene

in solr what is the difference between cloud and standalone mode, apart from:

1. The location of solr.xml: in the cloud mode is zookeeper, whereas in standalone it is located in solr_home.
2. blob store only available in cloud mode

what I want to know is :
does solr cloud mode differ from standalone mode in the fact that it uses an external zookeeper cluster vs an internal one ? 
and of course if there are other differences.
thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

> does solr cloud differ from standalone in the fact that it uses an
>   external zookeeper cluster vs standalone use an internal one ?

Yes both are different.

In the case of **Cloud mode** your data will be distributed and in terms of Solr, the index will be sharded on various machine, you could also add the replica to your shards to maintain the data redundancy. But in standalone the data will be available on the single machine. Please take a look in the image.

[image]

In case of standalone, there will be single index of europe-collection.

Zookeeper keeps the solr configuration and any changes in those config files will be reflected on all the Solr node which is hosting the different shards and their replicas.

You should use the external zookeeper as this is more cleaner approach as zookeeper is all together a different product.

Moreover in standalone mode there is no role of zookeeper.

Comment: It's worth noting that a "standalone" Solr server does not use Zookeeper at all, neither an internal or external one.